# Building a trace of flowrate vs time from a dataframe of discrete flows in an efficient manner using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe with some timeseries data.
Each row relates to a constant-flowrate demand of a fluid for a discrete duration.
I want to build a trace of total demand and can do so using "bare" python and some loops.
Is there a more efficient way of doing this using pandas?
I gather that looping or iterating over rows is inefficient and an anti-pattern.

The initial dataframe contains the following columns:

- `StartTime` (could be a datetime, int or float)
- `EndTime` (same unit as StartTime)
- `Rate` (int or float)

Below is basic example that uses itertuples rather than any pandas magic.
Is there a better way of implementing the `for row in streams.itertuples():` block using pandas?
Some method of creating a `entries` dataframe with two entries for each row in `streams`?

I'm presuming I still need to do some regular python to build the trace (the blocks after the above). Would it be possible to vectorize this?

```python
import pandas as pd
    
# Sample data (real data contains thousands of entries taken from an SQL database).
entries = [(1.2, 10.0, 3.1), (2.2, 6.8, 4.3), (3.5, 9.9, 3.0), (2.2, 7.6, 5.6), (4.6, 6.1, 2.2)]
streams = pd.DataFrame(entries, columns=["StartTime", "EndTime", "Rate"])

# Iterating over each row of the dataframe - would like to avoid this.
events = []
for row in streams.itertuples():
    events.append((row.StartTime, row.Rate))
    events.append((row.EndTime, -row.Rate))

# It would be nice to vectorize this and end up with a `trace` dataframe
# containing a `Time` column and a `Rate` column instead of two lists.
sorted_events = sorted(events)
times = [sorted_events[0][0]] # don't want to start at time = 0 if using datetimes
rate = 0.0 # assume rate is zero before starting trace
rates = [rate]
for time, rate_delta in sorted_events:
    rate += rate_delta
    if time == times[-1]:
        rates[-1] = rate
    else:
        times.append(time)
        rates.append(rate)
```

Comment: Hi, could you show what the expected dataframe should look like, given your initial sample data?

Comment: If you imagine a plot of flow versus time, each row in the input data would look like a rectangle with its base on flow = 0. The output is the superposition of these rectangles to create a totalized trace. It will look like a step function (i.e. it could be plotted with `matplotlib.pyplot.step (x=time, y=rate, where="post")`The output for running the above script is two lists; `times = [1.2, 2.2, 3.5, 4.6, 6.1, 6.8, 7.6, 9.9, 10.0]` and `rates = [3.1, 13.0, 16.0, 18.2, 16.0, 11.7, 6.1, 3.0999999999999996, -4.440892098500626e-16]`. What I'd like is a dataframe with times, rates as the columns.

Comment: You can visualise the output with `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.step(x=times, y=rates, where="post"); plt.show()`